# Ansible Playbook: only run specific tasks from roles

Tags: ansible

I guess I have a logical Problem. Maybe someone can help me doing on the right way.

I'd like to write a Playbook. This Playbook contains two roles:

- snapshots
- something

"Snapshots" contains 2 task/s(-files):

- create.yml
- remove.yml

"Something" contains several task/s(-files). Lets call them:
. main.yml

- something1.yml
- something2.yml
- and so on...

My goal is, that the playbook calls the tasks in the following order:

1. role: snapshots

   - task: create
2. role: something

   - tasks: all
3. role: snapshots

   - task: remove

I had in mind to work with tags. I could tag the Tasks of the roles, but I had no idea how to call a tagged tasks from a role.

So something different:
I could imagine that the playbook could look something like this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: snapshots
      tasks:
        - include_tasks: create.yml

    - role: something

    - role: snapshots
      tasks:
        - include_tasks: remove.yml
```

I've tried this Example but it didn't work. It runs thru every task of the role.

Any suggestions how to solve this on an nice way?

Comment: Have you tried using the 'when' conditional?

Answer (score 0):

Use [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html)

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - import_role:
        name: snapshots
        tasks_from: create

    - import_role:
        name: something

    - import_role:
        name: snapshots
        tasks_from: remove
```

, or use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html)

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - include_role:
        name: snapshots
        tasks_from: create

    - include_role:
        name: something

    - include_role:
        name: snapshots
        tasks_from: remove
```

You can combine the import and include. See [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#including-and-importing).